# Combine Two MySQL Tables Without Duplication (No previous topic provided solution)

Tags: mysql

I am at the edge of my sanity here. I have looked around at possible solutions before posting my problem, and I could not find any to solve my problem.

I have three tables with the following layout:

```
     Employee                User_logs                        Assessment
|----------------| |----------------------|-------| |----------------------|-------|
| empID  | uName | | checkindate | status | FK_ID | | asDate     |saResult | FK_ID |
|----------------| |----------------------|-------| |----------------------|-------|
| 1      | Tino  | | 2020-04-04  | Clear  |   1   | | 2020-04-04 | Pass    |   1   |
| ...    | ...   | | 2020-05-05  | Fail   |   1   | | 2020-05-05 | Pass    |   1   |
| ...    | ...   | | 2020-07-07  | Fail   |   1   | | 2020-06-06 | Fail    |   1   |
| ...    | ...   | | 2020-08-08  | Clear  |   1   | | 2020-08-08 | Pass    |   1   |
| ...    | ...   | |------------------------------| | 2020-09-09 | Pass    |   1   |
|----------------|                                  |------------------------------|
```

empID is a Primary Key I use as a Foreign Key in tables User_Logs and Assessment. The desired result I am looking for is as follows:

```
                    Result
| FK_ID  |   resultDate | Status| Result |
|----------------------------------------|
|   1    | 2020-04-04   | Clear | Pass   |
|   1    | 2020-05-05   | Fail  | Pass   |
|   1    | 2020-06-06   |       | Fail   |
|   1    | 2020-07-07   | Fail  |        |
|   1    | 2020-08-08   | Clear | Pass   |
|   1    | 2020-09-09   |       | Pass   |  <---- Not shown
|----------------------------------------|
```

I do get close with the following code, however for some reason it does not pick up on the very last entry of 2020-09-09:

```
SELECT A.checkindate, A.status, B.saDate, B.saResult
FROM myDatabase.User_logs AS A 
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT saDate, saResult, FK_empID
        FROM myDatabase.assesment
      ) AS B 
      ON  B.FK_empID = 1
      AND B.saDate = A.checkindate
WHERE A.FK_empID = 1
ORDER BY A.checkindate DESC
```

What am I doing wrong or not seeing ?

Comment: A table on the right hand side of a left join can never provide a value if its row matches nothing on the left. What you need is a consistent set of dates (a generated sequence) onto which both your result and your assessment are left joined

Comment: While doing the upmost to protect your sanity, please also consider ours. Accordingly, please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go at refining this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT fk_id, checkInDate as d FROM user_logs WHERE fk_id = 1 
    UNION 
    SELECT fk_id, asDate FROM assessment WHERE fk_id = 1
  ) datelist

  LEFT JOIN user_logs ul 
  ON 
    datelist.d = ul.checkindate AND 
    datelist.fk_id = ul.fk_id

  LEFT JOIN assessment a 
  ON 
    datelist.d = a.asdate AND 
    datelist.fk_id = a.fk_id
```

The basic concept is we produce a unique list of dates for employee 1, onto which we join the logs and the assessments. These joins will always work out in one case or the other (maybe both), by definition, because the things we are joining on came from the tables originally

I've left the join to Employee out of the query for clarity - I'm trying to explain to you why this works and yours doesnt - you can inner join the Employee table onto the datelist, and arrange for the columns you want in the SELECT

---

In terms of the original query, it was `logs left join assessment` - this means because there is no `2020-09-09` value in logs, the 2020-09-09 rows from assessment is just tossed out; essentially when doing a left join you say to the DB, "here is all the info I'm mainly interested in on the left, and also I'd like to know if anything from the right matches to it" - you told the db you weren't interested in the 2020-09-09 row implicitly as a result

You could flip it around, so that assessment is "mainly what you're interested in" and then show logs only if they match up, but then you might get the same problem with assessment not having a row that you want from logs

FULL OUTER JOIN is often used for things like this - youre saying with that "i'm equally interested in these things on both sides, and if it has a match on the other side, great.. If not, I'm not gonna be upset"

---

The technique presented in this answer is a little different; we build a unique list of dates that is definitely all encompassing (it has all the logs dates and all the assessment dates, then duplicates removed) so you can then claim "this is definitely 100% the list of dates I'm interested in, and if there is a logs, great, if there's an assessment, great, if not in either case, it's ok too"

Comment: I am still not getting that very last entry to show. I've marked it as the solution because you have shown an explained why my code will not work. That is more valuable than providing me with code to solve the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad - typo in the join (`ul` where it should have been `datelist`) - see the revision

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63c6be91ac203a88bf9a8ebde5b7a8ca - mysql <8 won't support the WITH (but I only use it to generate example tables)

Comment: Thanks for the dbFiddle. I have a question based on the first JOIN in the fiddle where you have the following: "LEFT JOIN user_logs ul ON datelist.d = ul.checkindate AND datelist.fk_id = datelist.fk_id". Is there a specific reason why you compare "datelist.fk_id = datelist.fk_id" ?

Comment: Hah, because I'm having a muppet moment and fixed the typo on the wrong line (the line it wasn't a typo on). I've amended the answer's SQL to be correct, and an adjusted fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18604518a055adfb67cf0d0c8db83edd

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e.empID, d.resultDate, u.Status, a.saResult Result 
FROM Employee e
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT checkindate resultDate
             FROM User_logs
           UNION 
             SELECT asDate
             FROM Assessment ) d
LEFT JOIN User_logs u ON e.empID = u.FK_ID AND d.resultDate = u.checkindate
LEFT JOIN Assessment a ON e.empID = a.FK_ID AND d.resultDate = a.asDate
-- WHERE COALESCE(u.Status, a.saResult)
-- ORDER BY empID, resultDate
```

Comment: Akina: thank you for your reply. You are confusing me a little because you are using columns in my "Desired Result" output with the data tables. Could you please correct your code to reflect only the Data Tables. Or should it be like that ?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was a mistake on your part or a misinterpretation on my part. Nonetheless, before this escalates, I will fiddle with your code. Thank you once again.